# matplotlib with controling colors

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am plotting this data file, which is working fine.

```
def orb_p():
  #  print(data[:,0])
  pxp = data[:,3]
  pxm = data[:,4]
  pyp = data[:,5]
  pym = data[:,6]
  pzp = data[:,7]
  pzm = data[:,8]
  plt.plot(x,pxp, "-")
  plt.plot(x,pxm, "-")
  plt.plot(x,pyp, "-")
  plt.plot(x,pym, "-")
  plt.plot(x,pzp, "-")
  plt.plot(x,pzm, "-")
  plt.fill_between(x,pxp)
  plt.fill_between(x,pyp)
  plt.fill_between(x,pzp)
  plt.fill_between(x,pxm)
  plt.fill_between(x,pym)
  plt.fill_between(x,pzm)
  plt.show()
```

The problem is I want to use same color for pxp and pxm (same for (pyp,pym) and (pzp, pzm)). I can manually control them using options like (`r-`), but I want to use default color scheme (`ggplot`). How I can do that?

Comment: you can reference a color in the matplotlib color cycle with a simple string, e.g., `'C0'`, `'C2'`

Answer (score 0):

By default `fill_between` should not advance the color cycler. So plotting the respective `fill_between` directly after the according `plot` should give them both the same color.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,2, 23)
data = np.fliplr(np.cumsum(np.cumsum(np.random.normal(size=(len(x),9)), axis=0)+3, axis=1))

for i in range(3,9):
    plt.plot(x,data[:,i], "-")
    plt.fill_between(x,data[:,i])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Mind that you don't actually need the `plot` function. Leaving it out gives the same result.[image]

*Although I have no idea why this works, if `fill_between` would not advance the color cycler.;-)*

Answer (score 0):

To access a used color in the color wheel:

```
l, = plt.plot(x)
color = l.get_color()
```

I haven't tried it for `fill_between` but I think you may need

```
l = plt.fill_between(...)
color = l.get_cmap()
```